# Loading Audio with Javascript

Tags: javascript, audio

There is a loadtime lag for calling the audio that should fire when each div is clicked/tapped, specifically for mobile devices.

Is there a way that I can consolidate the javascript in order to make the recordings load and play faster?

see demo here:
https://codepen.io/db13/pen/53525608544bf70c97ed0bf564a5efcc

html:

```
    <div id="header"></div>

<div id="mainWrapper">

  <div id="main">
    <div id="row-5">
      <div onclick="stopPlayHTMLBeep();" id="item01"></div>
      <div onclick="stopPlayHTMLSassy();" id="item02"></div>
      <div onclick="stopPlayHTMLhole();" id="item03"></div>
      <div onclick="stopPlayHTMLsnail();" id="item04"></div>
      <div id="item05">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="row-5">
      <div id="item01">
      </div>
      <div id="item02">
      </div>
      <div id="item03">
      </div>
      <div id="item04">
      </div>
      <div id="item05">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="row-5">
      <div id="item01">
      </div>
      <div id="item02">
      </div>
      <div id="item03">
      </div>
      <div id="item04">
      </div>
      <div id="item05">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="row-5">
      <div id="item01">
      </div>
      <div id="item02">
      </div>
      <div id="item03">
      </div>
      <div id="item04">
      </div>
      <div id="item05">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="row-5">
      <div id="item01">
      </div>
      <div id="item02">
      </div>
      <div id="item03">
      </div>
      <div id="item04">
      </div>
      <div id="item05">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="row-5">
      <div id="item01">
      </div>
      <div id="item02">
      </div>
      <div id="item03">
      </div>
      <div id="item04">
      </div>
      <div id="item05">
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>







<audio id="beep" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/226140/263133__pan14__tone-beep.wav" preload="auto"></audio>

<audio id="sassy" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/226140/20180306-202037.m4a" preload="auto"></audio>


<audio id="hole" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/226140/20180306-225920.m4a" preload="auto"></audio>

<audio id="snail" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/226140/20180306-231547.m4a" preload="auto"></audio>
```

JS:

```
    function stopPlayHTMLBeep () {
  document.getElementById("beep").load();
  document.getElementById("beep").play();
}


function stopPlayHTMLSassy () {
  document.getElementById("sassy").load();
  document.getElementById("sassy").play();
}


function stopPlayHTMLhole () {
  document.getElementById("hole").load();
  document.getElementById("hole").play();
}

function stopPlayHTMLsnail () {
  document.getElementById("snail").load();
  document.getElementById("snail").play();
}
```

Comment: I think precaching or preloading is what you need, take a look [here](https://createjs.com/tutorials/SoundJS%20and%20PreloadJS/)

Comment: If an answer works you should UP arrow it so the answer gains attraction,  the person is rewarded for their effort and the OP plays the game

Comment: I tried to do that, but it cannot be seen because I do not have enough "reputation points".

Answer (score 0):

Try calling `.load()` method on all of them right after the element is loaded.

```
<audio id="beep" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/226140/263133__pan14__tone-beep.wav" preload="auto"></audio>

<audio id="sassy" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/226140/20180306-202037.m4a" preload="auto"></audio>


<audio id="hole" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/226140/20180306-225920.m4a" preload="auto"></audio>

<audio id="snail" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/226140/20180306-231547.m4a" preload="auto"></audio>

<script>
document.getElementById("beep").load();
document.getElementById("sassy").load();
document.getElementById("hole").load();
document.getElementById("snail").load();
</script>
```

Comment: Wow, that helped. Thanks!